# what is the right way to give credit to an author when using code snippets found on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, comments

From time-to-time I find small useful functions on StackOverflow.  Specifically, these are bash functions with very few lines of code.  I typically make small name changes to local variables and the function name itself.  If I use the slightly modified code in a public-domain project, what is the correct way to give credit to the original author?  What is the best practice?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Depends on what, how much and how you use things, but if anything is needed, most of the time just a link back should suffice. And you would add that anyway for documentation, right? (Not a lawyer, so don't depend on it.)

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed.  That seems a sensible approach.